# Помогите распарсить следующую структуру на javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xmlparser

Необходимо помочь с кодом на javascript, или вообще сказать можно ли это сделать. Пример входных данных которые надо распарсить приведен ниже, то что нужно как раз из этих данных вытащить хранится под тэгами loc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"> 
<url>
    <loc>http://url.com/</loc>
    <lastmod>2020-07-04</lastmod>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>http://url.com/about.html</loc>
    <lastmod>2020-07-04T08:34:48+01:00</lastmod>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>http://url.com/create</loc>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
</url> 
</urlset>
```

Необходимо вытащить эти адреса, можно их потом сложить в отдельный массив или иной вариант который вам удобен, главное как их извлечь.

Comment: А так не получается getElementsByTagName ?

Comment: А сами пробовали? А как к вам попадают данные? В броузере или текстом?

Comment: Данные вообще идут по url из браузера, но с этим не думаю что сложно будет, главное как их вытащить. getElementsByTagName — данная конструкция вроде работает когда по html документу ищешь, не совсем понятно как ее применить когда я могу использовать входные данные откуда угодно, то есть будет ли в таком случае работать

Comment: Тогда, вам как минимум необходимо определиться с входными данными. Либо это коллекция, либо текст. Только тогда вам можно дать ответ. А универсальные методы писать вряд ли кто будет.

Comment: Тогда входные данные, это файл, который лежит в одной дирректории с .js, расширение файла .xml

Comment: Вообще идея с getElementsByTagName неплохая, но как ее реализовать если тэги во внешнем файле, я погуглил, но пока не нашел ответа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var xmlStr = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"> 
<url>
    <loc>http://url.com/</loc>
    <lastmod>2020-07-04</lastmod>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>http://url.com/about.html</loc>
    <lastmod>2020-07-04T08:34:48+01:00</lastmod>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>http://url.com/create</loc>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
</url> 
</urlset>`

var parser = new DOMParser()
var xml = parser.parseFromString(xmlStr, 'application/xml')

var res = Array.from(xml.querySelectorAll('loc')).map(x => x.textContent)
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const str = `
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
    <loc>http://url.com/</loc>
    <lastmod>2020-07-04</lastmod>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>http://url.com/about.html</loc>
    <lastmod>2020-07-04T08:34:48+01:00</lastmod>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>http://url.com/create</loc>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
</urlset>
`

const regexp = /(?<=<[Ll][Oo][Cc]>)([\s\S]*?)(?=<\/[Ll][Oo][Cc]>)/g

const urls = str.match(regexp)

console.log(urls)
```

Думаю, что можно их извлечь таким образом:

```
const url = './sitemap.xml'
const xml = new window.XMLHttpRequest()
xml.open("GET", url, false)
xml.send("")

const regexp = /(?<=<[Ll][Oo][Cc]>)([\s\S]*?)(?=<\/[Ll][Oo][Cc]>)/g

const urls = xml.response.match(regexp)

console.log(urls)
```

Comment: Ошибку пишет: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name
message: "Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name"
line: 9

Comment: @Mikhail Посмотрите пожалуйста пример кода, здесь всё работает

Comment: Странно, я даже когда нажал выполнить код у вас в комментарии выдает ошибку, попробую сейчас еще на другом устройстве

Comment: @Mikhail "Примерить" регулярное выражение можно тут: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Да, спасибо)) Проверил на другом устройстве, заработало. По неизвестной мне причине код не работал на моем планшете, но с компьютера все запустилось

Comment: @Mikhail, потому что предпросмотр назад - это ES2018.

Comment: `[Ll][Oo][Cc]` - извращение какое-то.